# How can i disable the status bar pop-up in firefox, particularly for HTML5 fullscreen video?

Tags: firefox, windows-8.1, video, html5

It is particularly problematic when watching a streaming video in an HTML5 player in fullscreen mode.

Currently my workaround is to cancel loading the and hopefully the player will reset and just load the video from then on. Honestly though, I want to be able to turn off the text directly.

Answer (score 1):

There are **add-ons** that can do this, such as [Status-4-Evar.](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/status-4-evar/)

In the Add-On options, set `Show status in:` to `None` to disable messages in the status bar.

[image]

---

You can also do this **manually** with configuration files.

Navigate to your profile folder (`"%APPDATA%\Mozilla\"`), then go to the `chrome` folder there, creating it if necessary. In the `chrome` folder, create a plain text file named `userChrome.css`

Paste the following in to that file:

```
@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"); /* only needed once */

.statuspanel-label {background:#FF9!important;color:black!important;font-family:"DejaVu Sans Mono"}

statuspanel {display:none!important}
statuspanel {max-width:90%!important}

statuspanel[type="overLink"] .statuspanel-label
statuspanel[type="status"] .statuspanel-label[value^="Looking"]
statuspanel[type="status"] .statuspanel-label[value^="Connect"]
statuspanel[type="status"] .statuspanel-label[value^="Waiting"]
statuspanel[type="status"] .statuspanel-label[value^="Transfer"]
```

[Ref1](http://kb.mozillazine.org/UserChrome.css)
[Ref2](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/969955)

Comment: I got it disabled with status-4-evar. This would be a perfect answer if you detailed exactly what status-4-evar options would disable the status bar, particularly in HTML5 fullscreen. I just unchecked everything and luckily something just so happened to work.

Comment: Added info for Status-4-Evar setting

Comment: Sadly, “Status-4-Evar” is no longer available and no clear alternative exists.